# Where to place templates for nested routes in Ember.js apps using pods?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-cli

Where should the template files be placed for nested routes when using the pod structure in ember-cli?

Here is what I have at the moment.

- Visiting `/foo` works

  - Expected and actual result: `app/foo/template.hbs` gets rendered.
- Visiting `/foo/bar` does not work, I get "Error: Assertion Failed: The URL '/foo/aa' did not match any routes in your application"

  - Expected result: `app/foo/bar/template.hbs` gets rendered.
  - Actual result: "Error: Assertion Failed: The URL '/foo/bar' did not match any routes in your application"

Router:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('foo', function() {
        this.resource('foo.bar', function() {
        });
    ));
    /* ... */
});
```

Folder Structure:

```
/app/pods
    /foo
        controller.js
        route.js
        template.hbs
        /bar
            controller.js
            route.js
            template.hbs
```

Should I be defining my routes differently or naming my files differently?

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation page, it says "app/templates/  Your Handlebars templates. These are compiled to templates.js. The templates are named the same as their filename, minus the extension (i.e. templates/foo/bar.hbs -> foo/bar)."

Actual result: "Error: Assertion Failed: The URL '/foo/aa' did not match any routes in your application"

It is searching for **/foo/bar/bar.hbs** , however your case is **/foo/bar/template.hbs**

Naming convention is the key role of ember.js.

**Route**

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('foo', function() {
        this.resource('bar', function() { // 'bar' route nested in 'foo' route

        });  
    });
});
```

[Getting Started](http://www.ember-cli.com/#getting-started)

Comment: Sorry, the code example that I listed above, I used `aa` instead of `bar` - my mistake. I have edited it to reflect what I meant to say!